# How to install offline ng2-pdfjs-viewer package under the Angular application

Tags: angular, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

How can I install and use the **ng2-pdfjs-viewer offline** in **angular**, because I do not want to install it every time and how can I build for production with an offline package of it?

Comment: If you want it to be separately installable, you have to make it a different app.

Comment: Not want to be separate application

Comment: One app is one JS bundle, there is no conditional there, only thing you can do is use routing to separate them into lazy loaded parts, but when saving the app via ServiceWorker, it will download all of it every time...